# Add values to an array inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to edit an array on the fly, inside a `foreach` loop. I basically analyse each key, and if this key match the one I want, I want to add another entry in the array **immediately after this one**.

If I take this code,

```
$values = array(
    'foo' => 10,
    'bar' => 20,
    'baz' => 30
);

foreach($values as $key => $value){
    print $value . ' ';
    if($key == 'bar'){
        $values['qux'] = 21;
    }
}
```

I've got 2 problems,

- first, the output is `10 20 30` instead of the expected `10 20 30 21`
- second, even if I solve the first problem, my value will still be added *at the end* of my array

**How could I add the `qux` entry between `bar` and `baz` ones?**

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: It's probably because you're not creating a new array, but use the old array to store the value in. That's why it's at the end of your array. To do what you want to do is to make a new variable let's say `$aData` and insert the values in there with your `foreach` loop.

Comment: You don't need a second array to achieve this. Instead of `foreach` use a `for` loop and iterate through the length of the array and using the index variable of the for loop, add whatever you want to your array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Foreach will not loop through new values added to the array while inside the loop.

If you want to add the new value between two existing values, you could use a second array:

```
$values = array(
    'foo' => 10,
    'bar' => 20,
    'baz' => 30
);
$newValues = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) 
{
    $newValues[$key] = $value;
    if($key == 'bar') 
    {
        $newValues['qux'] = 21;
    }
}
print implode(' ', $newValue);
```

Also, see one of my favorite questions on StackOverflow discussing the foreach loop: [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Comment: @Dennis Then you should have posted it as an answer instead

Comment: Upvoted your comment ;) But it was not there when I started writing the answer.

Comment: I know @LarsEbert, i don't blame you haha. And meagar, yea could do that.. but Lars already did so.

Comment: Thanks. As I expected, it seems I'll need to loop twice on my array. One time to add the value, and one time to treat the array...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ampersand sign before the value.

```
//populate all the promos into their promoG groups
foreach($unclaimedPromoGroups as &$unclaimedPromoGroup) {
    $_promo = new Promo();
    $_promo->promoGroupID = $unclaimedPromoGroup['promo_groupID'];
    $promo = $_promo->getGroupPromos();
    $unclaimedPromoGroup["promos"] = $promo;
}
```

Comment: This is such a simple and elegant solution, very good!

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to create a new array,

```
<?php
$values = array(
    'foo' => 10,
    'bar' => 20,
    'baz' => 30
);

$newarray = array();
foreach($values as $k => $v) 
{
    $newarray[$k] = $v;
    if($k == 'bar') 
        $newarray['qux'] = 21;
}

echo implode(' ', $newarray);
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/N4XgB

Comment: This will not add the new value between bar and baz.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses the same array.

```
$values = array(
    'foo' => 10,
    'bar' => 20,
    'baz' => 30
);

function match($niddle, $haystack, $push, $offset = 0) {
    foreach(array_slice($haystack, $offset) as $key => $value) 
    {
        print $value . ' ';
        if($key == $niddle) 
        {
            $i = array_search($niddle, array_keys($haystack)) + 1;
            $haystack = array_slice($haystack, 0, $i, true) + $push + array_slice($haystack, $i, count($haystack) - $i, true);
            $haystack = match($niddle, $haystack, $push, $i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return $haystack;
}

$values = match('bar', $values, array('qux'=>21));

var_dump($values);
```

Comment: It still does not print the new value in the same loop.

Comment: Sure, the new entry is added. But unfortunately the `foreach` loop wont access it.